# Unable to connect to an Oracle database using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, winforms, entity-framework-6

I am working on a PoC Windows application which accesses an Oracle database using Entity Framework. I use Visual Studio 2017 and .Net Framework 4.7.2

I referred to the links below:

- [DB first with Oracle](https://csharp.today/entity-framework-6-database-first-with-oracle/)
- [Oracle Link](https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/dotnet/2015/entityframework_linq_modelfirst/Entity%20Framework%20LINQ%20and%20Model%20First.html#section2)

I've installed these Nuget packages:

- Entity Framework 6.2.0
- Oracle ManagedDataAccess Entity Framework 19.3.1

I also have Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio installed. 12.2.0.10

Somehow I am not viewing the same Visual Studio database connect window as shown on the screens from the links. I have attached a sample screen from my end.

Below image is what I actually see on my end:

[image: What I see on my Visual Studio]

Can someone support me with this issue?

Comment: @marc_s - Do you need any additional details? May I know why have you marked it as a not useful ticket ?

Comment: I have not marked this question as anything - I just fixed a few typos and Capitalization mistakes ...

Answer (score 0):

Well I found the solution to for my issue. This might help someone who is facing a similar issue.

I found out that I was using a wrong version of Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio 2017.

I uninstalled it from Tools -> Extensions and Updates (Search for Oracle)

Do not uninstall from Programs and Features it does not help.

Install the version : 18.3

https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/dotnet-odacmsi-vs2017-downloads.html

This solved the issues for me. Hope this helps someone who faces a similar issue.